# Why do I get a Red Exclamation after I have done a Update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have Tortoise SVN installed and am using it in Windows Explorer.  A colleague has updated some files I assume because I had a exclamation point on some folders.  I did a update to get the latest version but I still see a red exclamation point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A Red exclamation mark tells you that you have modified these files in your working copy, so to get rid of the exclamation marks, you have to either commit the files (update the version in the repository with your modified version) or revert them (throwing away your changes).

Comment: How do I know if someone else has made changes then?

Comment: Just do a SVN update - if someone made changes, your working copy will be updated to reflect the latest changes.

Comment: Is there no way to know that someone has made changes?

Comment: According to http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html, you could use check for modifications, followed by check repository, but honestly, I don't see the point - we've been using Tortoise for 5+ years, and I never ever would have needed such a function.

Comment: I do an update every morning before starting to work, and infrequently (perhaps about 5 times) during the day.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, your solution is not the case with me.  I checked out a repo on my desktop.  I don't have admin rights on my work PC, only company Sys Admins.  By default, TortoiseSVN uses the Admin acct on each box to show the icons on working copies.  Other users have to manually select any other drives to enable the icons on working copy in the icon overlay settings.  Afterwards, I did SVN Update.  When I open TortoiseSVN in Win Exp, I see a heap of red exclamation icons on files I haven't modified. They date before I worked here.  What can I do to make all the icons green in this repo? Thx!

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I did the clean up as well.  I also toggled between "default" and "shell" in the icon overlay settings to see if that worked.  But the red icons are still there. Should I just delete my local repo and start over again?  Would that give me a fresh copy? I hope this isn't a stupid question! I haven't done any work on the code yet, so I have no fear of losing any changes.  I've been using Git so long, and I've never really used Tortoise, only Subversion plugin within eclipse. Thx!

Comment: @Chris22 If you're sure that you didn't do any modifications, I'd suggest you start with a fresh checkout. If the problem persists, you should post a new question on StackOverflow (perhaps including a reference to this question and an explanation why your problem is slightly different).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt ok, thanks. I'll do the fresh checkout and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

@Frank is quite correct on the staleness indicator but--based on your followup comments in his answer--it sounds like your concern is getting a handle on other people's edits rather than your own edits. Many developers, as you intimated, periodically do an update to freshen the working copy with commits from others, the canonical "[pull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology)" model (vs. the "[push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)" model).

Let me digress a moment to shift views to justify my next point more clearly. Consider the typical bug tracking system using the **pull** model: when others submit or update bugs, **you** need to go to the website (or client) and search and filter and check for what might have changed on issues you are interested in. Some systems support only that. But the better ones also support the **push** model: you can subscribe to projects or specific issues so that when something new is posted you **automatically** receive an email. *(I could not work well without this feature!)*

The situation is analogous in the subversion domain. Yes, I frequently do an svn update to absorb all changes, but I find it quite helpful to be notified when something I have keen interest in is changed by someone else. And doing this is simple: download Stefan Kung's [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html) that adds push technology to Subversion. This tool sits in the system tray on a Windows system, and lets you specify any number of repositories, either at the root, or at any subdirectory, so you can adjust the resolution as fine as you like. Don't mean to sound like an advertisement--I have no connection with the product or author--but I just found this quite recently and I have found it simple to use, unobtrusive, and clean--it just works.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently seen the red exclamation mark persist after SVN cleanups and updates due to multiple files having the same name but different casing in the same repository folder. Tortoise SVN allows multiple files to exist in the same location with the same name with mixed casing, but Windows does not.

As an example, at one location in the repository, 2 files existed: **f**ile.txt and **F**ile.txt. When I would go to SVN update the working copy, file explorer would only allow one of these files to exist, so only one would be included in my working copy after an SVN update.

When I ran “check for modifications” on my working copy, Tortoise SVN reported that the file that couldn’t be checked out was missing, since it was not allowed to be checked out to my working copy folder.
To resolve this, I deleted one of the duplicative files from the SVN repository and ran an update on my working copy.